# Android know international number's country code

Tags: android, contacts, phone-number, country-codes

Basically I will have a list of numbers in database in E.164 format.
But usually numbers in contacts are not in the same format they contain 0 OR 00 OR None as prefix while saving them.

0 AND None can be checked via adding prefix of user's country code. But what about 00 ones. How can I verify them in database. if I use a like query [ex like '%num'] after eliminating 00 it might check for other invalid numbers present in someones contact list.

How can I overcome this problem as checking them against every known country code prefix will be very slow also?